# My info doesn´t erase after uninstall the app

Tags: android

I made an app that use the sharedPreferences and i storage some info there, when i uninstall the app and install again the info storage there always appear, i don´t know why. I don´t programming anything to keep them there.

I just upgrade my Galaxy S to 2.2.1 and i did a back up of all my apps including that i made, i don´t know sure if Android does not erase correctly the app.

I did uninstall others apps like facebook one and apparently erase all files fine.

I need suggestion of what can i do, please.

Comment: Sounds like a bug - try creating a new file with your app, uninstalling, and then reinstalling. Is the new file still around?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem too, and the problem is in the Galaxy S 2.2.1 ROM. It is buggy.

It saves the shared preferences in **/dbdata/databases/app-package**

Unfortunatelly when you uninstall the application that place is not cleared! It's frustrating.

It makes SharedPreferences completely useless in Galaxy S. When you uninstall, re-install the app you can never change SharedPreferences again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an open question anymore but so long as you follow the rules in the [Internal Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) API then the files should be deleted for you automatically when the project exits.

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage... When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.